# Ordenar elementos en un RecyclerView usando StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Tags: android, recyclerview

Estoy creando una aplicación donde los usuarios crean elementos con una imagen y se muestran como una lista. Se parece a Google Keep, donde los elementos creados no tienen la misma altura pero si el mismo ancho, distribuidos en dos columnas. El orden en que los elementos son creados es importante y deben estar ordenados de esa manera, de arriba hacia abajo. Como se muestra en la foto cada número representa el orden en que los elementos fueron creados, no está ordenados de la manera esperada.

[image: imagen vista mosaicos]

¿Hay alguna manera en que se puede definir como los elementos deben ser ordenados? Me gustaría ordenarlos:

1 2

3 4

5

y así sucesivamente.

Este es el fragmento de código donde inicializo el RecyclerView, el adaptador y el Layout Manager:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
AdapterRecyclerView adapterRecyclerView = new AdapterRecyclerView(getContext(), list);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterRecyclerView );
StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
```